# Не работает конкретно функция diff в PHP для времени

Tags: php

Почему некорректно отрабатывает функция для разницы во времени в PHP. В настоящий момент 15:25 15.02.2018, но для времени 2018-02-16 16:00:00 он выдает разницу в:
$diff: 2160. Почему такое может быть?

```
foreach ($response['orders'] as $order) {
$order['customFields']['time_perezvona'] = str_replace('tp', '', $order['customFields']['time_perezvona']);
if (strlen($order['customFields']['time_perezvona']) < 4) {
$order['customFields']['time_perezvona'] = substr_replace($order['customFields']['time_perezvona'], ':', 1, 0);
} else {
    $order['customFields']['time_perezvona'] = substr_replace($order['customFields']['time_perezvona'], ':', 2, 0);
}
$order['customFields']['time_perezvona'] .= ':00';
$time_sled_shaga = $order['customFields']['data_sled_shaga'] . ' ' . $order['customFields']['time_perezvona'];
echo $time_sled_shaga . '<br>';
$datetime1 = new DateTime($time_sled_shaga);
$datetime2 = new DateTime('now');
$interval = $datetime1->diff($datetime2);
$diff = $interval->format('%h') * 3600 + $interval->format('%i') * 60 + $interval->format('%s');

echo '$diff: ' . $diff . '<br>';

if ($diff < 7200) {
    $infoForEdit = array(
        'id' => $order['id'],
        'status' => 'srochno'
    );

// $response2 = $retail->request->ordersEdit($infoForEdit, 'id', $order['site']);

    // echo "<pre>" . print_r($response2);
}
}
```

В цикле вывожу и $diff и вот пример двух значений:

2018-02-16 9:00:00

$diff: 62995

2018-02-16 16:00:00

$diff: 1795

Comment: Обновил вопрос.

Comment: Также обновил вопрос.

Comment: а нельзя просто свойства объекта использовать? зачем форматирование?

Comment: Это как, например?

Comment: Странно, ибо на эти два значение у меня выводи: `15608 и 40808` *(точно уж не 1795..)*

Comment: а сам diff как таковой вообще зачем? Для datetime реализованы операторы сравнения. `if ($datetime1 < new datetime('-2 hour'))` если я правильно понял что вы хотите сделать.

Comment: @Мелкий, отработало для условия 2018-02-15 13:30:00
$infoForEdit: 76375 (это id, просто вывел, но условие таки отработало, при этом сейчас 16:06.

Comment: Но вообще должно отрабатывать именно в большую сторону. То есть если разница между указанным временем и текущем составляет меньше 2-х часов (а указанное изначально больше).